# State Space Model in Python

Tags: python, state, space

I am trying to fit the following time varying regression model using Python.

> *y<sub>t</sub>* = *b<sub>t</sub>* *x<sub>t</sub>* + *n<sub>t</sub>*
>
> *b<sub>t</sub> = b*<sub>*t*-1</sub> + *v<sub>t</sub>*

Here *b* is the time varying slope and intercept while *x* is the exogenous independent variable which is known.

Any idea how I can do that? I tried looking into Statsmodels, specifically the packages wrote by Chad Fulton but could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

State Space models can vary widely across various fields.

I have found it best to implement them using numpy arrays. In the end, you will be working on vectors and matrices. This approach gives the most flexibility and can be powerful when combined with scipy routines.

Comment: can you perhaps provide a simple example where the observation equation has exogenous regressors? thanks